# Javafx get CategoryAxis categories Nodes

Tags: java, charts, java-8, javafx-8

Is it possible to get (a list) of the Nodes created by a chart (specifically a BarChart) which create the categories of the CategoryAxis?

[image: Bar Chart]

The goal is to add some Mouse Event to thoses Nodes.

I have tried to acces them via `xAxis.getChildrenUnmodifiable()` but this return the tick mark.
There is also `xAxis.getCategories()` but this return the label text of the categories which are `String` and to add Mouse Event I need `Nodes`.

So here is some code that reproduce what I want to accomplish :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";
    final static String italy = "Italy";
    final static String usa = "USA";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final CustomBarChart<String, Number> bc =
                new CustomBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        bc.setLegendVisible(false);
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));


        final Label tooltipXAxis = new Label("");
        tooltipXAxis.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12;" +
                "-fx-font-weight: bold;" +
                "-fx-padding: 5px;" +
                "-fx-background-color: white;" +
                "-fx-background-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-color: black;");
        tooltipXAxis.setVisible(false);

        //xAxis tooltip 
        for (Node n : xAxis.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            n.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    tooltipXAxis.setMouseTransparent(true);
                    tooltipXAxis.setText("Tooltip Here");

                    tooltipXAxis.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            n.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point2D locationInScene = new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY()-35);
                    Point2D locationInParent = group.sceneToLocal(locationInScene);

                    tooltipXAxis.relocate(locationInParent.getX(), locationInParent.getY());
                }
            });
            n.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    tooltipXAxis.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }

        bc.getData().addAll(series1);

        group.getChildren().addAll(bc, tooltipXAxis);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public class CustomBarChart<X, Y> extends BarChart<X, Y> {

        Map<Node, TextFlow> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

        public CustomBarChart(Axis xAxis, Axis yAxis) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            this.setBarGap(0.0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void seriesAdded(Series<X, Y> series, int seriesIndex) {

            super.seriesAdded(series, seriesIndex);

            for (int j = 0; j < series.getData().size(); j++) {

                Data<X, Y> item = series.getData().get(j);

                Text text = new Text(item.getYValue().toString());
                text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 10pt;");

                TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(text);
                textFlow.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

                nodeMap.put(item.getNode(), textFlow);
                this.getPlotChildren().add(textFlow);

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void seriesRemoved(final Series<X, Y> series) {

            for (Node bar : nodeMap.keySet()) {

                Node text = nodeMap.get(bar);
                this.getPlotChildren().remove(text);

            }

            nodeMap.clear();

            super.seriesRemoved(series);
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutPlotChildren() {

            super.layoutPlotChildren();

            for (Node bar : nodeMap.keySet()) {

                TextFlow textFlow = nodeMap.get(bar);

                if (bar.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() > 30) {
                    ((Text) textFlow.getChildren().get(0)).setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    textFlow.resize(bar.getBoundsInParent().getWidth(), 200);
                    textFlow.relocate(bar.getBoundsInParent().getMinX(), bar.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + 10);
                } else {
                    ((Text) textFlow.getChildren().get(0)).setFill(Color.GRAY);
                    textFlow.resize(bar.getBoundsInParent().getWidth(), 200);
                    textFlow.relocate(bar.getBoundsInParent().getMinX(), bar.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - 20);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the Label `tooltipXAxis` is shown when the Tick Marks or the xAxis Label are hovered.
However, the goal is to display it when the categories labels are hovered as shown in the image above.

Comment: The linked image should be posted as an attachment.

Comment: I need 10 reputation points to do this, which I dont have. Can someone do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293155/how-to-paint-peak-map-in-javafx/45315401#45315401) where I extracted `xAxis` line from a chart to move it up. May be it will help you. Otherwise, could you provide your code, I will play with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So maybe I can use `xAxis.getStyleClass().contains("categories")` or `xAxis.lookupAll("categories")` but how can I find the String corresponding to the categories of the Axis? I only found `"axis-label"` and `"axis-tick-mark"` which would give the same result as `xAxis.getChildrenUnmodifiable()`. I added the code to the question.

Comment: I played with your code, no quick solution for reasonable time.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. Thank you for your time!